# Nested Functions - missing Argument for parameter

Tags: swift, func

I have been trying to make a function inside another function where the output of the getPoolInfo will be (Func1:Double, Func2:Double).

I really need your help guys.

```
func getPoolInfo(PoolLength:Double, PoolWidth:Double, ShallowDepth:Double,DeepDepth:Double)->(Double,Double)
{

//To calculate the Area of the Pool
func Area(PoolLength:Double,PoolWidth:Double)-> Double
{
    let area = PoolLength * PoolWidth
    return area
}

//To calculate the Volume of the Pool
func poolVolume(PoolLength:Double, PoolWidth:Double, ShallowDepth:Double,DeepDepth:Double)->Double{

    let area = PoolLength * PoolWidth
    let avgDepth = ((ShallowDepth + DeepDepth) / 2)
    let volume = area * avgDepth


    return volume
}

return (Area(),poolVolume())

}
```

getPoolInfo(PoolLength: 12, PoolWidth: 6, ShallowDepth: 1, DeepDepth: 3)

> Missing argument for parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
return (Area(),poolVolume())
```

to

```
return (Area(PoolLength:PoolLength,PoolWidth:PoolWidth),poolVolume(PoolLength:PoolLength, PoolWidth:PoolWidth, ShallowDepth:ShallowDepth,DeepDepth:DeepDepth))
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro, it works, but it give me (.01 60,.02 120)
It should give (60,120).

Also I would like to make the func volume to take the asnswer area from the Area Funciton do you know how to do it

Comment: @AnanAlmasri print(getPoolInfo(PoolLength: 12, PoolWidth: 6, ShallowDepth: 1, DeepDepth: 3) gives (72.0, 144.0)